# How to display images form a mongoose on html

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Hello I am working on a web application using node.js, express and javascript. 
I am really confused about how display a collection of images which is returned from mongoose.

```
      imageModel.find().where("createdBy", username).
        exec(function(err, imagesByUser) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
        console.log("User at getUser is: "+ imagesByUser);
        if (imagesByUser != null) callback(imagesByUser);
      });
```

Then I try to send imagesByUser form my index.js to jade file 
I tried multiple approaches to pass images as a array in json

```
res.json(images);
```

I just wondering how to iterate json array in jade file and display these images. 
Thanks ! 
Larry

Answer (score 0):

Your images must be on another server like S3, so the image is only a URL that you send to template, is not necessary pass a json.

```
res.render('template.html', {imageByUsers: imageByUsers})
```

on template with Swig.js

```
<img src="{{ imageByUsers.image }}" />
```